# There are at most five elements

Tags: first-order-logic

I must write this sentence in first-order logic. I've written it this way

$\forall(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,x_5)[\neg(x_1=x_2)\wedge \cdots \wedge  \neg(x_4=x_5) \wedge \forall x (x=x_1)  \lor \cdots \lor (x=x_5)]$

What I am trying to say here is that if there are more than five elements, that element will be equal to any of the ones I stated before, which guarantees that there are five elements at most. Am I right?

Comment: What does the negation of that multiple equality mean? You can omit it anyway, since the sentence still says there are at most $5$ elements. If you want to say "exactly 5" then you need all $10$ inequalities among the the $x_i$'s.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming $x_1 = x_2 = x_3 = x_4 = x_5$ is shorthand for all $10$ inequalities between them, negating it just says "$x_1, x_2, \dots, x_5$ are not all equal". This is not actually necessary here, since we have an "at most" in the statement; it also doesn't guarantee that all five elements are different.

Leaving it out, we *almost* get what you want. There's one problem: starting the statement with $\exists$ means it's only true if there is *at least one* element.

To avoid making any such assumptions, we have to use $\forall$ statements (or the negation of $\exists$ statements) only. Here's one way to do it: $$\forall (x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4, x_5, x_6)[(x_1 = x_2) \lor (x_1 = x_3) \lor \dots \lor (x_5 = x_6)]$$ In other words "if you take six elements, at least two of them must be equal". You could write a similar statement beginning with $\neg\exists$ which would translate to "there do not exist six elements, all different".

Comment: Usually, domains are non-empty in first order models, so it’s ok under that assumption to leave the five existential quantifieRs, since in this sense “at most $5$ elements” (in the domain) is equivalent to “1 or 2 or 3 or 4 or 5 elements.” It would be different to express “at most $5$ solutions to $A(x)$” where that phrase allows $0$ solutions.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your formula is that it entails the existence of at least one element -- but "at most five" also permits for "zero".

Also, as pointed out in the comments, a chain of equialities is not defined in the language of first-order logic; what you want to say is probably $\neg(x_1 = x_2) \land \ldots \land \neg(x_4 = x_5)$.

Instead, say that there do not exist six distinct elements:

$$\neg \exists x_1 \ldots \exists x_6 (\neg(x_1 = x_2) \land \ldots \land \neg(x_1 = x_6) \land \ldots \land \neg (x_5 = x_6))$$

That no domain restriction is specified is fine, if the instructions don't say so.